# Spring Boot | Session Replication | Mode COOKIE

Tags: spring-boot, session-cookies, tomcat9, httpsession, session-replication

I have a spring boot application up and running.
We run it using external standalone tomcat behind LB.

Tomcat version - 9

Springboot - 2.3.4.RELEASE

I have tried with below approach but none works.

**web.xml**

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
  </session-config>
  <display-name>availment</display-name>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.session.tracking-modes=cookie
```

**Javax-servlet**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

But none seems to work, user gets logout as soon as request reaches another server where login request did not come.

Comment: Do you have session replication between the servers? Otherwise you cannot spread the requests

Comment: @SimonMartinelli With jboss (Only spring framework not springboot) it still works. Not sure if we need to do any settings in tomcat + springboot

Comment: Yes JBoss den do that https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/beta422/html/clustering-http-app.html

Comment: Checkout this https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/cluster-howto.html